# If $A,B$ be a pair of disjoint set finite sets. How to prove by induction that if $A \sim m, B \sim n$, then $A \cup B \sim (m+n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, induction

Let $p(n)=A\cup B \sim (m+n)$, by induction over $n$:

$p(1)=A\cup B \sim (m+1)$

$B \sim 1$, then  let $B= \{{b_1}\}$

By induction (again) over $m$:

$g(m)=A\cup B \sim (m+1)$, then $g(1)=A\cup B \sim (1+1)$ for $A \sim 1$, let $A=\{ a_1 \}$

Well, here are my questions:

$1)$ I'm not totally secure if in this case $1+1=2$, because $1$ is the set with only one element and with the same $1$  gives me the same element.

$2)$How i can start to make the proof in the first case g(1)?

Answer (score 1):

1)  when you say 1+1=2, that's a claim about the *number* of elements; it does not mean that you have the same element twice, let alone that $1$ is that element. Indeed, the 1 element in $A$ is $a_1$, which can be $bananas$ for all we know, and the 1 element in $B$ is $b_1$ which could be $Elvis \ Presley$. Given that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, we know for a fact that $a_1 \not = b_1$, so the union $A \cup B$ in that case will have 2 elements.  So we're good here.

2) I wouldn't do induction over m in the first place. Just do induction over n. That is, prove by induction over $n$ that for any $n$ it is true that for any $m$: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $A \sim m$ and $B \sim n$ then $A\cup B \sim (m+n)$.

Comment: how i can start the proof when i reach the part $A \cup B \sim (m+(n+1))?$, i really don't know where i can use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: OK, so the inductive hypothesis is that for any disjoint $A$ and $B$ where $A \sim m$ and $B \sim n$, we have $A \cup B \sim m + n$.  So now we take disjoint $A$ and $B$ where $A \sim m$ and $B \sim n + 1$. We can say that $B = \{ b_1, .., b_n, b_{n+1} \}$. So: $A \cup B = A \cup \{ b_1, .., b_n, b_{n+1} \} = A \cup (\{ b_1, .., b_n \} \cup \{ b_{n+1} \}) =  (A \cup \{ b_1, .., b_n \}) \cup \{ b_{n+1} \}$. Now, since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, $A$ and $\{ b_1, .., b_n \}$ are disjoint as well, and so we can use our inductive hypotheses, and so $A \cup \{ b_1, .., b_n \} \sim m + n$. ... part I

Comment: ... (part II) OK, let $C = A \cup \{ b_1 , ... , b_n \}$.  Then  $C \sim m+n$. Now, if we made sure to actually do the universal proof *inside* the inductive proof, then we already established by the base case that for any $A$ with $A \sim m$ and any $b \not \in A$: $A \cup \{ b \} \sim m +1$. So: $C \cup \{ b_{n+1} \sim (m+n) +1 = m + (n+1)$. And so: $A \cup B = C \cup \{ b_{n+1} \} \sim m + (n+1)$, completing the inductive step.